# Python Popen shell script but fail

Tags: python, bash, shell, subprocess, popen

I want to execute bash command

```
 '/bin/echo </verbosegc> >> /tmp/jruby.log'
```

in python using Popen. The code does not raise any exception, but none change is made on the jruby.log after execution. The python code is shown below.

```
>>> command='/bin/echo </verbosegc> >> '+fullpath
>>> command
'/bin/echo </verbosegc> >> /tmp/jruby.log'
>>process = subprocess.Popen(command.split(),  stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds=True)
>>> output= process.communicate()[0]
>>> output
'</verbosegc> >> /tmp/jruby.log\n
```

I also print out the process.pid and then check the pid using ps -ef | grep pid. The result shows that the process pid has been finished.

Comment: Using `split()` this way is a code smell. Don't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to `subprocess.Popen` is the array `['/bin/echo', '</verbosegc>', '>>', '/tmp/jruby.log']`. When the first argument to `subprocess.Popen` is an array, it does not launch a shell to run the command, and the shell is what's responsible for interpreting `>> /tmp/jruby.log` to mean "write output to jruby.log".

In order to make the `>>` redirection work in this command, you'll need to pass `command` directly to `subprocess.Popen()` without splitting it into a list. You'll also need to quote the first argument (or else the shell will interpret the "<" and ">" characters in ways you don't want):

```
command = '/bin/echo "</verbosegc>" >> /tmp/jruby.log'
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds=True)
```

Comment: This still fails when executing Popen. >>> process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/homes/sxu3/tools/python_install/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/homes/sxu3/tools/python_install/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: You're right: you need to add the `shell=True` argument to make `Popen` invoke a shell. I was careless. So: `subprocess.Popen(command,  stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds=True, shell=True)`

Comment: Arrays are usable both with and without `shell=True`, though their semantics vary wildly between the cases -- see my answer for an example of the former. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just use pass file object if you want to append the output to a file, you cannot redirect to a file unless you  set `shell=True`:

```
command = ['/bin/echo', '</verbosegc>']

with open('/tmp/jruby.log',"a") as f:
     subprocess.check_call(command, stdout=f,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, that is what I have done in my answer, I meant there is no way to use `>>` without using shell=True

Comment: Quite right, and as edited the commentary is no longer misleading; +1.

Comment: @shijiexu, I used check_call as I don't see the logic in using Popen when you want to redirect the output to a file.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
command = [ 'printf "%s\n" "$1" >>"$2"',  # shell script to execute
            '',                           # $0 in shell
            '</verbosegc>',               # $1
            '/tmp/jruby.log' ]            # $2
subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
```

The first argument is a shell script referring to `$1` and `$2`, which are in turn passed as separate arguments. Keeping data separate from code, rather than trying to substitute the former into the latter, is a precaution against shell injection (think of this as an analog to SQL injection).

---

Of course, don't *actually* do anything like this in Python -- the native primitives for file IO are far more appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried without splitting the command `and using shell=True`? My usual format is:

```
 process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
 output = process.stdout.read()       # or .readlines()
```